# How to set ADC clock in low power mode?

Tags: adc, stm32, clock-speed

I am measuring the voltage with the STM32L011K4 MCU. When the processor goes into low power sleep mode, I start reading the wrong values from an ADC. I think the reason is caused by the system clock settings. Because in low power mode only the LSI clock is running and the ADC is working with the MSI clock. So when the system clock changes, the ADC starts reading meaningless values. How to set the ADC before and after low power mode?

Answer (score 1):

> Because in low power mode only the LSI clock is running and the ADC is working with the MSI clock.

Actually, in low power mode the system runs on MSI, and the ADC runs by default on HSI16. You can however change the latter with the CKMODE[1:0] bits of the ADC_CFGR2 register. See **13.4.4 ADC clock (CKMODE, PRESC[3:0], LFMEN)** in the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00108282.pdf).

[image]